# UIscrollview with dynamic label and buttons

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have scrollview with buttons and labels.

I have for each buttons column and line for determining position.

example for buttons :

```
UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake([[element column] doubleValue]*60,[[element line] floatValue]*40,50, 30)];
```

I'd like the button to be center-aligned. How can I do this?

You can show here image : http://s28.postimg.org/jy4i3a2nh/Capture_d_cran_2015_07_16_16_46_00.png

Comment: Center aligned to what? it's parent(the `UIScrollView)`?
On a side note. sounds like you should use a `UICollectionView`

Comment: @Erakk but I do not see how to put a button in the middle with grid. yes UIScrollView is parent

Answer (score 0):

**Using `UIScrollView` - Updated**

You would need to save the reference to all buttons in a NSMutableArray, or just a reference to the title of the button, along with a ref to the button being centered:

```
@interface yourViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton *centeredButon;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIScrollView *scrollView;

@end;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
    //initialize the array
    self.buttonTitles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    // set all your button titles here somehow

    // create your views here.
    // i suggest you dont set their frames here. self.view has not the correct frame at this time

    // do other stuff you need here
}
```

We override `viewDidLayoutSubviews` to set the frames correcly

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    for (UIView *view in self.scrollView.subviews) {
        if (view == self.centeredButton) {
            view.frame = [self centerFrameForButton:button];
        } else {
            view.frame = [self frameForView:view];
            // i dunno how you set or get the element.line and element.column but this might need to be evaluated
        }
    }
}

- (void)setCenteredButton:(UIButton *)centeredButton {
    if (_centeredButton != centeredButton) {
        // if you want to animate the centering, you can do it here
        centeredButton.frame = [self centerFrameForButton:centeredButton];
        //if we had a centered button before, set it back to its original position
        if (_centeredButton) {
            _centeredButton.frame = [self frameForView:_centeredButton];
        }

        // now we update the variable
        _centeredButton = centeredButton;
    }
}

- (CGRect)frameForView:(UIView *)view {
    //use your logic to find the view frame.
    //to find its position properly, you could just get its index from the scrollView.subviews:
    NSInteger viewIndex = [self.scrollView.subviews indexOfObject:view];
    // find out its position and return the frame
    return CGRectMake([[element column] doubleValue]*60,[[element line] floatValue]*40,50, 30);
}

- (CGRect)centerFrameForButton:(UIButton *)button {
    CGFloat originX = (self.scrollView.bounds.width - button.bounds.size.width) / 2.f;
    CGFloat originY = (self.scrollView.bounds.height - button.bounds.size.height) / 2.f;
    CGRect centerFrame = CGRectMake(originX, originY, self.button.bounds.size.width, self.button.bounds.size.height);
    return centerFrame;
}
```